# Reloading in-edit-mode answer after someone else makes an edit hides the edit box

Tags: bug, edits, notifications, editor

I started to edit an answer on [Space Exploration](http://space.stackexchange.com) when someone else edited the same post and the notification bar appeared.

When I clicked the reload notification bar to reload the answer with edits, the edit box disappeared and it looked just like I hadn't ever clicked the "edit" action link.

In my case this wasn't a major issue, because the edit thus far was largely trivial, but I could easily see someone spending time on an edit only to have it pulled out from under them by being careless.

To add insult to injury, when I attempted to reload the page, I was asked to confirm that I wanted to leave the page, indicating that the edit box is still there, just not visible.